# Getting 500 error on passing authorization in angular js with $http.get()

Tags: angularjs

My problem is when I am calling this service via angularjs get method the header will be sent with it so 500 error will come.

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
        'ui.router',
        'ngTasty',
        'ngRoute',
        '720kb.datepicker',
        'angularFileUpload'
    ]);
    app.controller('newCtrl',function($scope,$http){
         $scope.subform = function(){
             $http({
                    method:'get',
                    url     : 'https://jsonodds.com/api/odds',
                    headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json','Accept': 'application/json','JsonOdds-API-Key': 'Api Key'} 
             }).success(function(data) {
                 alert(data);
                if (data.errors) {  alert('error');
                  // Showing errors.
                  $scope.errorName = data.errors.name;
                  $scope.errorUserName = data.errors.username;
                  $scope.errorEmail = data.errors.email;
                } else {
                  $scope.message = data.message;
                }
              });
                 //$http.get("action.php?action=list").then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.rows});     
         };
         //$http.get("action.php?action=list").then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.rows});
             $scope.getres = function(){
              if($scope.search == undefined){ 
             $scope.search="";
              }
              if($scope.perpage == undefined){
              $scope.perpage="5";
              }
               $http.get("action.php?action=list&search="+$scope.search+"&perpage="+$scope.perpage).then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.rows});  
             };
    });
```

Comment: Please format your code, this is unreadable.

Comment: I usually drink Sol, so I can't give you one.

Comment: did you check what's the stacktrace of the 500 error??

Comment: 500 is serverside error, check parameters that you passing. are you sure that api works properly?